# (Java) Ship projectiles speeding up as more ships fire

Tags: java, arrays, projectile

So I have a small game so far where you build ships and attempt to destroy the enemy station. Everything works fine except for when more than one ship is firing at the station. What seems to happen (or at least what I believe) is that the code for setting the location of the bullet is occurring as many times as there are ships. So I tried simply dividing the speed of the bullet by how many ships there are, but eventually the bullet ceases to move. Here is the code, as it is without any fix attempted.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 9999; j++) {
    if (PlayerMapData.weaponFireCreated [j]) {
        PlayerMapData.weaponFire [j].setLocation (
            (int) (PlayerMapData.weaponFire [j].x + playerMapData.weaponTravelSpeed * PlayerMapData.weaponFireDirectionX [j]),
            (int) (PlayerMapData.weaponFire [j].y + PlayerMapData.weaponTravelSpeed * PlayerMapData.weaponFireDirectionY [j])
        );
```

Hit detection happens below. Is the the setLocation statement the problem or do I have to differentiate between what bullets belong to what ship?

EDIT: Should have specified that this is in a timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was simply because the weaponFire array(s) were one dimensional, and thus were referenced by multiple ships. Using a 2D array fixed the problem since ships now have "ownership" of the bullets they fire, instead of attempting to move every bullet fired by any ship.

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure to check only once:

```
 if (PlayerMapData.weaponFireCreated [j] && !PlayerMapData.alreadyUpdated[j]) 
 { 
           ...
           PlayerMapData.alreadyUpdated[j]=true;
 }
```

You are not scanning whole map for each ship instance, are you?

Comment: The map itself is actually stored in a different class than PlayerMapData. PlayerMapData stores the bullet location along with ship location, width, etc. Wouldn't checking if alreadyUpdated cause it to check it once and never again? So the bullet would shoot and then not move, right?